# CheckBox diseño del check iOS Multiple

Tags: swift, xcode

Me gustaria poder tener este diseño

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Son CheckBoxs los edittexts

Ideas por favor

Comment: Con las líneas verticales?

Comment: @Bicho si asi es con las lineas verticals es el problema no se como calcular los medios dependiendo el telefono

Comment: Si utilizas contenedores o `views` te pueden ayudar al momento de trabajar con los `constraints`. Así te despreocupas un poco por el tema de pantallas si tienes los `textbox` directamente en el `ViewController`.

Comment: Podrias darme un ejmplo mas practico? @Bicho

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asumiendo que tienes los checkbox y que el problema es el cálculo de los centros de la línea vertical, te adjunto imágenes de cómo deberías tener los `constraints`.

1. Debes tener un contenedor o `view` principal, en el ejemplo le puse de color negro.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las constraints de este contenedor son:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. Dentro del contenedor principal agregas dos `view`, el de color azul y blanco con los `constraints` hacia el contenedor principal y entre ellos (Puedes escoger la opción de agregar automáticamente).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3. Dentro del contenedor azul agregas los checkbox y las líneas horizontales. Esto es el `constraint` del primer conector.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

4. Así sería la estructura de los componentes en el `Storyboard`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este sería el resultado final si ejecutas en el simulador en diferentes dispositivos, puedes ver que se ajusta al tamaño de la pantalla y los checkbox mantienen su diseño.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si no tienes los checkbox, este [link](https://github.com/penumutchuprasad/LKCheckBox) es el que utilicé para el demo.

Este es el código:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var v1: CheckBox!
    @IBOutlet weak var v2: CheckBox!
    @IBOutlet weak var v3: CheckBox!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //Configuras la forma de los checkbox.
        
        self.v1.style = .square
        self.v2.style = .square
        self.v3.style = .square
    }

}
```

Comment: Tendras este ejemplo que puedas subirlo algun repo? disculpa la molestia , Me costo un poquito poder seguirte todo la verdad

Comment: Acabo de subirlo. Avísame si puedes clonarlo `git@bitbucket.org:bichoec/checkboxrepo.git`

Comment: Me pasarias para clonar https?, esto me dice que no es una "url valida"

Comment: Esa sentencia me da bitbucket. Intenta la url `https://bitbucket.org/bichoec/checkboxrepo/src/master/`